# Restore a Mac to its factory settings

Tags: macos, mac, restore

I have a Mac mini M1 2020.  The new machine came with iMovie, GarageBand, Keynote, Pages, Numbers, etc.

Will restore a Mac to its factory settings also include those aforementioned applications?

Comment: Yes but you can download them from the mac App Store to avoid having to completely restore your Mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. iMovie, GarageBand, Keynote, Pages, Numbers are free on recent Mac Os X versions , from Mojave I think : https://www.apple.com/om/creativity-apps/mac/